# Transfer stuck for 2 days with "Unconfirmed incoming transaction found in the txpool" message. Why and what can I do?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-confirmation

I withdrew some XMR from an exchange two days ago to test the transfer on my new own linux wallet that I run with the CLI. The daemon is running, in sync, and has incoming and outcoming connections.

I generated an integrated address to receive the XMR amount. Using the show_transfers command, I can see the incoming transaction with the corresponding payment id and amount. However it's stucked there for 2 days now and my balance is 0, and when I check the transaction the following message is displayed: "Unconfirmed incoming transaction found in the txpool".

I don't understand how it can just be in the transaction pool for two days without being confirmed and I don't know what to do to get my coins since everything seems to be running fine.

Edit: I'm using v0.13.0.2 release, the exchange is Kraken, and the transaction id shows up on xmrchain.net with 1533 confirmations.

Comment: If you feel comfortable sharing the transaction ID, can you? What exchange did you use? Are you using the latest Monero v0.13 release?

Comment: Added more info in edit, but I prefer not to share the transaction ID.

Comment: Does it show up in https://xmrchain.net? MoneroExplorer.com is stuck on Monerov7 (0.12).

Comment: It does! Thanks, I edited again. Seems like I have a problem with my wallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use rescan_bc then save_bc once completed.